# How can i put this is one derivative function?

Tags: javascript

```
var dx = 0.001;
function f(x) {return x*x}
function d(x){return (f(x+(dx/2)) - f(x-(dx/2))) / dx}
function d2(x){return (d(x+(dx/2)) - d(x-(dx/2))) / dx}
function d3(x){return (d2(x+(dx/2)) - d2(x-(dx/2))) / dx}
```

I have these functions to calculate the derivative, is there a way to place these all in one function that takes and x as an input and and n for the nth derivative?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/derivative.html)
and call this function in a loop/recursion